# Angular 11 - Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Tags: angular

I have an angular 11 app with a module named `admin-layout` inside the default app module.

Here is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrModule } from "ngx-toastr";

import { SidebarModule } from './sidebar/sidebar.module';
import { FooterModule } from './shared/footer/footer.module';
import { NavbarModule} from './shared/navbar/navbar.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutes } from './app.routing';

import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes,{
      useHash: true
    }),
    SidebarModule,
    NavbarModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    FooterModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Inside the `app/layouts/admin-layouts`, I have the `admin-layout.module.ts` as:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AdminLayoutRoutes } from './admin-layout.routing';

import { DashboardComponent } from '../../pages/dashboard/dashboard.component'

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularSvgIconModule } from 'angular-svg-icon';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(AdminLayoutRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    HttpClientModule, 
    AngularSvgIconModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
  ]
})

export class AdminLayoutModule {}
```

Now inside the component `app/pages/dashboard/dashboard-components.ts`, I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
import Chart from 'chart.js';

import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Details</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-body">
              <li *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
                {{i}} {{item}}
              </li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() data: [];

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-cmp',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

  public data = [];

  httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private http: HttpClient) {}

    ngOnInit(){
      const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent, { size: 'xl' });
      this.http.get<any>(environment.api_url + 'stats').subscribe(data => {
        for(var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(data["pole"]).length; i++){
            data.push(data["data"][i]);
        }
        console.log(data);
        modalRef.componentInstance.data = data;
      })
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error - `Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'`

The `console.log(data)` yields me `(2) [3.81, 1.44]`

What am I doing wrong here? As from other stackoverflow answers, they need me to have `CommonsModule` import in the module. I have it both at the app level as well as the module level. Tried removing from one another also doesn't work.

Comment: Do you import the `BrowserModule` in your root module (`AppModule`)? Do you import the `CommonModule` from `@angular/common`?

Comment: Yes I tried importing `BrowserModule` in `AppModule` and in the sub module `Admin-Layout` tried importing `CommonModule` in that as well but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that - the modal block of HTML and the typescript code needs to be in another component and the modal component needs to be called inside the parent component. This way of working gives modular code and also avoids problems like this one where there is by definition no mistake or error.